# How long would an original gameboy last on a modern lithium battery?

Tags: batteries

The original Gameboy was famous for it's battery life on 4AA batteries. My HTC One smartphone can last about as long as the GB did back in the 80s.

So how long would an original gameboy last if powered by a modern lithium phone battery?

Comment: You'd need to know the average current draw of a Gameboy. Otherwise you're just handwaving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's compare the [energy densities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density#Energy_densities_of_common_energy_storage_materials) of the battery types:

- Alkaline battery, 1.8 MJ/L
- Lithium-ion, 2.36 MJ/L (best case)
- Lithium battery, 4.32 MJ/L

Therefore, if a Gameboy lasted 10 hours on Alkaline batteries, in theory it would last 40.3 hours on Lithium (primary, non-rechargeable), or 20.4 hours on Lithium-ion batteries that occupied the *same physical space.*

If you used a phone battery, it depends on its size and capacity. Most phone batteries aren't as large as four AA batteries, so you would have to go by the capacity of the battery. Four [AA batteries](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/e91.pdf) (in series for 6V) have a capacity of around 2500 mAh at 100 mA discharge rate. (The [Gameboy Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Boy) indicates it requires about 0.7 watts which is a little more than 100 mA at 6V.)

An HTC One battery is a Lithium-polymer battery at 2300 mAh, which I'll assume is 3.7V LiFePO<sub>4</sub>.

Since the voltages are different, there would have to be some conversion which would introduce efficiency losses, but we'll assume 100% for now.

The four alkaline AA batteries then are 2500 mAh * 6V = 15000 mWh.

The HTC One battery is 2300 mAh * 3.7V = 8510 mWh.

Based on this, you'd get roughly *half* of the runtime using your phone battery.

Comment: According to http://blog.gg8.se/wordpress/2009/07/22/testing-gameboy-input-voltage-ranges/ the switching regulator in the Original GB requires about 4V to work normally, with 3V the lower limit of "okay". Oh, but to be fair, 4 AA batteries are really bulky. You could easily fit two regular HTC one batteries in the same space.

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly, an alkaline AA cell is around 2Ah, and 4 in series are 6V, so 12Wh.

An iPhone 5 battery is about 1.5Ah at 3.7V so less than 6Wh.

We might expect the Gameboy to run for roughly half as long on an iPhone 5 battery as it would on good quality fresh alkaline AA batteries.

An iPad 3 battery, on the other hand, is about 43Wh, so we might expect it to last about 3.5 times as long.

Answer (score 0):

A typical alkaline AA has about 3.9 watt-hours, so 4 AA batteries will have around 15.6 watt-hours. A Galaxy S5 lithium ion battery has 10.78 watt-hours.

So actually, the original Gameboy would have a shorter lifetime on a modern day lithium ion phone battery.

Comment: But you could probably fit two Li-Ion phone cells into the 4 AA battery compartment.